# How to use the maxgap argument of zoo::na.spline

Tags: r, na, zoo

I am having trouble getting `na.spline` to not impute values when the number of missing values is greater than `maxgap`. For example, the following gives the expected result:

```
library(zoo)
z = zoo(1:2, as.POSIXct(c("2019-11-13 20:59:12 GMT", "2019-11-14 20:59:12 GMT")))

na.approx(z, xout=seq(start(z), end(z), by="3 hour"), maxgap=2)

#2019-11-13 20:59:12 2019-11-13 23:59:12 2019-11-14 02:59:12 2019-11-14 05:59:12 
#                  1                  NA                  NA                  NA 
#2019-11-14 08:59:12 2019-11-14 11:59:12 2019-11-14 14:59:12 2019-11-14 17:59:12 
#                 NA                  NA                  NA                  NA 
#2019-11-14 20:59:12 
#                  2
```

however, `na.spline` imputes values even when the run of `NA`'s is greater than `maxgap`:

```
na.spline(z, xout=seq(start(z), end(z), by="3 hour"), maxgap=2)

# 2019-11-13 20:59:12 2019-11-13 23:59:12 2019-11-14 02:59:12 2019-11-14 05:59:12 
#               1.000               1.125               1.250               1.375 
# 2019-11-14 08:59:12 2019-11-14 11:59:12 2019-11-14 14:59:12 2019-11-14 17:59:12 
#               1.500               1.625               1.750               1.875 
# 2019-11-14 20:59:12 
#               2.000
```

- How do I use the `maxgap` argument for `na.spline` please?

Comment: Seems to be a bug but it works if you do it this way: `na.spline(merge(z, zoo(,  seq(start(z), end(z), by="3 hour"))), maxgap = 2)`

Comment: thanks @G.Grothendieck ; thanks for the workaround. Is it worth adding a bug report at the zoo r-forge page?

Comment: I have already done that.

Comment: great, thanks again @Gabor